# How to get the 'Release ID' of a windows server?

Tags: python, windows-10, windows-server

I am unable to find the release id(build version, looks like '1511' or '1803') of a windows server 2012 R2 Standard i need it for forming its CPE (common platform enumeration).

Being unfamiliar with all of this and getting to no such success i am not sure what to try either.
For getting this release id on windows ten i used REG Query and to execute that automatically i used python with subprocess.

This is the command i used to obtain the release id:

```
'Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId'
```

It successfully gave me the desired result for windows 10 but for windows server it gives:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Release Id (aka Windows 10 Release Id, in YYMM format) if only available for Win 10 and Windows Server 2016 or higher.

Maybe base your naming on Major / build version number?

A table of all versions:

- https://ss64.com/nt/ver.html (I find this more readable)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/

Answer (score 0):

Hey @rockangator there is a simple code in python given on www.google.com there because this question is not at all understandable, which you have written here..Try to be more specific next time please.